# Runtime database migration in .NET (does it exist?)

Tags: .net, database-migration

There are a lot of post about rails-like database migrations in .NET, but none of them seem to do what I want them to do.

I have a WPF project and we're using Prism to create loadable modules. What I'd like to do is allow the module to hand off a database migration to the core at load time, with migration and any seed data. If that migration already exists, it ignores it, otherwise it migrates (or updates if a new version- not sure how to work that)

It seems like all of the systems are using NAnt or MSBuild and I wondered if there was a framework out there for runtime migrations. If not, has anyone seen such runtime database manipulation elsewhere to emulate? Good directions or ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something like [FluentMigrator](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/)?

After more searching, I found this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/8033/50079

which has more valuable answers. Have a look at it as well.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but that still looks like it needs separate migration deployment, using an external .exe tool, NAnt, or MSBuild: https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Migration-Runners I was hoping to do it at runtime using Prism, dependency injection, or something similar.

Comment: @JohnMetta: No, it doesn't need an external tool. The external tools use the classes in the FluentMigrator project to do the migrations; there's nothing stopping you from including similar code in your own app. I 've written an external tool that does the migrations myself in exactly this way.